# camera in a js game, follow player

Tags: javascript, canvas, camera, transformation

So lately I've been trying to make a 2D Zelda-like game. I want to make a camera to follow the player.

So I looked at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/translate, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Transformations, and some others in my search (MDN has an article on it but I couldn't follow although it didn't look like what I was looking for).

I also didn't want to just center the player, I want to have a camera which has a limit, so you have to go a certain amount outside of the camera for the map to start scrolling.

```
function camera(data) {
    var x, y;

    if(I.x <= 2 && I.x >= -2 && I.y <= 2 && I.y >= -2) { x = 0; y = 0;}
    if(I.x >  2) { x = -I.size; y = 0; }
    if(I.x < -2) { x =  I.size; y = 0; }
    if(I.y >  2) { x = 0; y = -I.size; }
    if(I.y < -2) { x = 0; y =  I.size; }

    ctx.translate(x, y);

    draw.map();
    draw.camera();
    draw.players(data);

    ctx.resetTransform();
}
```

`draw.map()` draws the tiles.
`draw.camera()` draws a little dotted box so I know the boundary of the camera.
`draw.players(data)` draws every player.
`I.size` refers to the size of each tile(16 in this case).
`I.x` & `I.y` are self explanatory.

I do have a working version(uses node and socket.io):
http://dais-jaackotorus.codeanyapp.com:8080/

EDIT:

Almost forgot! The problem with this code is that it follows the player for only one tile and then it doesn't any longer, and it goes outside of the camera range instead of staying inside and I dont understand why.

Comment: Trying to understand. You want to make a zelda-like tiled navigation, where you see only a small portion of a map? What do you expect to happen when the player walks to the edge of the dotted box?

Comment: @Jorg Originally I wanted it to follow the player. The problem was that I had no reference point. So right now the grid is static. Also the dotted box is just aesthetic, More importantly the whole map should continue moving to the left if I keep pressing `d`, but it only does it once, that's the real bug.

Comment: From the looks of things, `map` draws only the visible part of the grid, correct? So, 21 out of 63 tiles. That's the part you have to change around the position of the player, so instead of starting to draw at 0, start drawing at player position - width/2. In that case, do not move the player, move the map instead. When you reach the edge of the screen, move the player and not the map.

Comment: @Jorg I so-so understand what you're saying, could you explain further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simplified example:

https://jsfiddle.net/2xbo0kas/

The trick is to start drawing the world around the player. So, in the jsfiddle, you can see the player is stationary but the map moves, so that the player is always centered into the viewport.

What the fiddle does not show is the final position of the player once you reach the edge of the map (where you'd draw a stationary map but update the player rectangle).

```
function draw() {
  var startx = Math.max([player.x - size.width], 0);
  var endx = Math.min(startx + size.width, map.length);
  var starty = Math.max([player.y - size.height], 0);
  var endy = Math.min(starty + size.height, map[0].length);

  for (var x = startx; x < endx; x++) {
    for (var y = starty; y < endy; y++) {
      var drawx = x - startx;
      var drawy = y - starty;

      //draw tile
    }
  }

  //draw player
}
```

Comment: Oh! So instead of transforming the map, you're simply selecting what portion of the map you're going to draw?

Comment: And another thing, Sorry if I didn't write it correctly, but the desired behavior is so that when your relative `x` and `y` values go outside of a centered box, then the map will translate(as long as I get an answer to the previous question I'm accepting your answer, just so you know).

Comment: I’ve never transformed anything, only drawn the bit I needed. But, I’m not an expert. Just keep recalculating the starting x and y according to your needs

Comment: This way you can make giant maps while being reasonably memory efficient

Comment: the translation you're talking, is this the "zelda-tile", where you walk out of one screen and into another? Let's call that a submap. The principals are more or less the same, only instead of binding the min/max stuff to the size of the whole map, use the size of the sub-map. Then check what submap you're on in relation to the whole map.

Comment: @julian.a.avar look: https://codepen.io/_jorgt/pen/rdmPqE?editors=1010#0

Comment: Thank you! I wish I could give you more credit, this helps me so much :)